# Hilbert space problem

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

> Let $(H, (\cdot,\cdot))$ be a Hilbert space over complex numbers and $x,y\in H$. Suppose $$|(z,x)|\leqslant |(z,y)|$$ for all $z\in H$. Is it true that $x=\lambda y$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb C$?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I think no but i couldn't find a counterexample

Comment: Why do you think this is false?

Comment: Because our condition in terms of inequality but we require equality. So i think this is false not claiming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true.  Put $x=\alpha y$, where $|\alpha|\leq1$.

Given the edit to the question, observe that if $(z,y)=0$, then $(z,x)=0$.  So $\{y\}^\perp\subset\{x\}^\perp$, and use this to show that $x\in\text{span}\{y\}$.

Comment: I am sorry. Actually I mean $x = \lambda y$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb C$.

Comment: Then yes.  Observe that $\{y\}^\perp\subset\{x\}^\perp$, and from this the result follows.

Comment: please could you explain more precisely

Comment: @Bekzod Aweygan has given you a good hint so you can try the problem on your own.